# I want to make register and login functionality with spring security using jdbcUserDetailsManager class and its methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to make register and login functionality with spring security using jdbcUserDetailsManager class and its methods.
I have made, but I want to implement something where I need help.
Whenever I register a user it is getting enabled but I have nowhere used the logic to get enabled.
What I want is that whenever a user registers it will be disabled automatically. After the approval of admin the user will get enable along with a role.
Please help.[Please refer to the highlighted column]`

Pojo Class:

```
package com.web.spring.model;

public class UserRegistration {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Controller Mapping:

```
        @RequestMapping(value="/register",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView register()
        {
            return new ModelAndView("registration","user", new UserRegistration());
        }

  @RequestMapping(value="/register",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView register1(@ModelAttribute("user") UserRegistration user1)
    {   if(user1.getUsername()!=null && !user1.getUsername().isEmpty() 
    && user1.getPassword()!=null && !user1.getPassword().isEmpty()) {
       List<GrantedAuthority>  authorites= new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
       //authorites.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
       authorites.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
       String encodedPwd=bCryptPassworEncoder.encode(user1.getPassword());
       User user=new User(user1.getUsername(),encodedPwd,authorites);

       jdbcUserDetailsManager.createUser(user);

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/login");}
       else {
           return new ModelAndView("registration");
       }
    }
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYQo3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want is that whenever a user registers it will be disabled automatically.

Consider using `UserBuilder` method `disabled`, eg.:

```
jdbcUserDetailsManager.createUser(
  User.withUsername(user1.getUsername())
    .password(encodedPwd)
    .authorities(authorites)
    .disabled(false)
    .build()
);
```

Alternatively, you could use more complex constructor with `enabled` being passed as 3rd parameter:

```
public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled,
            boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired,
            boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities)
```

Your current approach:

> `User user=new User(user1.getUsername(),encodedPwd,authorites);`

According to documentation with this constructor - all boolean arguments are set to **true**, including `enabled` parameter.

That's the reason why there's value `1` in `ENABLED` column in database.